# Firebase Push Notification is not received by some devices

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to establish a device to device communication through firebase. It's like, if you comment on someone's post, he will get a push notification "X commented on your post". I am generating the device_token through this line of code

```
String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

Everything worked great since I noticed that one of my devices wasn't receiving push notification. I took a look on all devices tokens. Where all devices with **152 characters** device_token were receiving push notification perfectly, this one device (Samsung Grand Prime) was generating a device_token of **140 characters**.

Example of tokens I'm receiving:

Can receive push:>> dNRy512gHWY:APA91bEmbb8c....aWTwIvYQ = 152 characters

Can't receive push:>> APA91bG....TO16iag = 140 characters (before the colon part is missing here)

Google Playstore in the device is updated and signed in. What can be the issue here?

**Edited**

It's working fine if I send push from firebase web console to that device using the same token id. It's really getting weird now!

Comment: It seems that you are using different types of tokens, with and without the colon. Could you check if you are using different FCM/GCM SDKs to generate the tokens, you should be using one.

Comment: The problem was solved after reinstalling the application. But still wondering, why it would generate such **bad** tokens which are unable to perform its task? And yes, I am using the same sdk for generating tokens. @ArthurThompson

Comment: Not sure why you ended up with different types of tokens, but the FCM SDK should never generate tokens without the colon. So if you see that happening again please report to firebase.google.com/support.

Comment: Already reported. Lets see what happens.

Comment: So you are able to reproduce generating tokens without the colon with the new FCM SDK?